# Access pdf file from within my jar

Tags: java, java-io

I want to be able to open a help PDF file on mouse click, the PDF file is contained with the `.jar` (and imported to Eclipse).

I am calling `Help();` with a mouseListener (added via windowbuilder). The mouse event is working correctly. The issue I am having is I am unsure how to access the PDF file, I keep getting `NullPointerException`s reported.

My current code was;

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {     
        java.io.InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/nullpdf.pdf");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        br.close();
        isr.close();
        is.close();
        File afile =new File(line);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(afile);
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("NO PDF READER INSTALLED");
    }
}
```

I also tried a more full file path to the nullpdf (I.E "package/co/uk/TabSync/nullpdf.pdf") but had the same `NullPointerException`.

I have now edited the code to write a temp file but it still isnt working:

```
public void Help() {
         if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
              try {
String tempFile = "nullpdf";
              System.out.println(tempFile);
            File temp =File.createTempFile(tempFile, "/home/geeky/Desktop/nullpdf.pdf");
              Desktop.getDesktop().open(temp);
              }
              catch (IOException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                  System.out.println("NO PDF READER INSTALLED");
              }
         }
    }
```

I also tried an absolute path to a pdf file on my desktop as well as just nullpdf.pdf.  If i use just nullpdf.pdf then i get a leafpad window that opens with nothing in it.  If I try the direct file path to my dekstop I get the following:

```
NO PDF READER INSTALLED
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1717)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1738)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1850)
```

Do I need to do something to give the application permission to write to my file system (I am used to android dev. and that is often an issue there).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a silly question, is the PDF really inside your JAR? Besides, you might want to might want to copy the PDF as bytes, not as `String`s, I'm not sure whether the latter will result in a usable PDF file.

Comment: Change `catch (IOException ex) {` to `catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();` & copy/paste the result as an edit to the question.  Also `File afile =new File(line);` where exactly is that `line` defined?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: can you mark the line where its throwing NPE

Comment: @AndrewThompson - `line` is clearly defined in the `try` block, though it may not contain the proper data.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/file");
```

The path must start with "`/`", as it is in your `classpath`. So if your file is in `com.test` and your file is `myPDF.pdf`, then your path should be `/com/test/myPDF.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File afile =new File(line);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(afile);
```

above code wont open a file until the file is physically written on disc. you missed file writting code.

usage of `File(line)` is wrong. `File()` constructor takes `String` which is **file path** not **data**. 1st `create()` a file, write data on it. and pass the `File` to `open()` method

**EDIT:**
Also, instead of creating file at random location, create a temp file

```
File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
```

write data on it and pass it to `Desktop.open()`

**EDIT:2**
**1st of all you should not use reader/writers for any non-plain-text file. PDF is not a plain text. It is formatted. You should read it as stream only.** The code below works. but make sure you include it in jar file.
one way to do this in eclipse is goto project-properties>java-build-path>source add a folder here and keep pdf file in it.

```
public void Help() {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.pdf");
            byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(data);
            is.close();
            String tempFile = "file";
            File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(temp);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("NO PDF READER INSTALLED");
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: here is how you can write a file to disk http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: agreed that `line` doesn't have proper data, but its well within the scope.

Comment: actually it was not proper indented. SO got confused. the remaining answer is still valid

Comment: thanks for the reply. is there an easy way to temporarily copy the PDF from the jar file to the disk, then open it with desktop?

Comment: thanks, but what file path should I use to write the PDF from the jar? do I need to get class/get resources as stream as well?

Comment: in this case you should create temp file. 
File temp = File.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf"); then pass to Desktop.open()

Comment: Edited first post.  I am not able to get the temp file to open the pdf either.

Comment: no need to add '/' in tempfile name, just add extension. as i wrote ".pdf"

Comment: Same error I am afraid with just "nullpdf.pdf".  I have the pdf file in the package, in the \src\package folder.  What else am I missing?

Comment: String tempFile = null; // it cant be null
File temp =File.createTempFile(tempFile, "/nullpdf.pdf");

Comment: Ok, so what should I initialise the String tempFile to?  I have tried String tempFile = "nullpdf" some progress as a leafpad (notepad in linux) window is called but its empty (and clearly not the pdf I want to open!).  Thank you for your help so far

Comment: ok... so now the only issue, i think, remains is to package the pdf into jar (since you r able to invoke app but since pdf is not read, the temp file is empty). just check opening the jar that pdf exist in it or no. if no add the pdf in a folder in project in eclipse. it will bundle automatically

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still getting the Nullpointerexception.  I have the PDF file copied to the jar, i have added it via Eclipse and have even tried copying in it to each folder in the JAR file manually to make sure its available (not tidy I know).  Does it matter that I am using Linux?  The multiplatform support was the reason I went for opening the PDF with isDesktopSupported

Comment: Also, is there a way I can return the filepath to the temp file as a string?

Comment: @ay89 your code is working perfectly if I run from my netbeans ide but if I run from outside netbeans it says **There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not repaired**

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly use this

```
try {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String path = jTextField1.getText();
    System.out.println(path);
    Path tempOutput = null;
    String tempFile = "myFile";
    tempOutput = Files.createTempFile(tempFile, ".pdf");
    tempOutput.toFile().deleteOnExit();
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/JCADG.pdf");
    Files.copy(is,tempOutput,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
    {
        Desktop dTop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(dTop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN))
        {
            dTop.open(tempOutput.toFile());
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```